# Delay-Free Switched-Capacitor Integrator Difference Equation Derivation

Tags: operational-amplifier, charge, integrator, switched-capacitor

I want to derive the difference equation of a delay-free SC integrator using charge-domain analysis.

Here's the example I am following. This shows you that for charge domain derivation, all you need is to write out the law of conservation of charge. The example below is straight-forward.

[image]

I want to apply the same methodology to derive the transfer equation in the charge domain for the circuit below (it is straight-forward in the voltage domain).

[image]

Here is my thought process.

- The positive node of \$C_1\$ is connected to \$V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]\$ and
  the negative node is connected to virtual ground. Therefore, at the
  end of phase 1, \$C_1\$ has a charge of
  \$C_1 \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]\$.
- The positive node of \$C_2\$ is connected to the output node and the
  negative node is connected to virtual ground. Before \$\varphi_1\$
  turns on, \$C_2\$ has a charge of
  \$C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1]\$. When \$\varphi_1\$ turns on, the
  charging current through \$C_1\$ also flows through \$C_2\$. This
  charging current moves a charge of \$C_1 \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]\$
  through the circuit. Hence, the amount of charge in \$C_2\$ at the end
  of \$\varphi_1\$ is \$C_2 \cdot
            V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] - C_1 \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]\$.
- The amount of charge in the circuit at the end of \$\varphi_1\$ is the
  sum of the charge stored in \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$:

  $$
  C_1 \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n] + C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] - C_1
  \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]
  $$
- During \$\varphi_2\$, \$C_1\$ is discharged to ground, while \$C_2\$
  retains its charge. So, at the end of \$\varphi_2\$, the charge in the
  circuit:

  $$
  C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] - C_1 \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]
  $$
- By the principle of conservation of charge:

  $$C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] = C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] - C_1
                \cdot V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]
  $$

The above result make no sense. The correct difference equation is:

$$C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n] = C_2 \cdot V_{\mathrm{out}} [n - 1] - C_1 \cdot
V_{\mathrm{in}} [n]
$$

Comment: You seem to have a labeling/indexing error. When, during a full cycle, do you consider the index to have advanced?

Comment: I am using the methodology in the first screenshot I posted.

Comment: The screenshot includes Vos, and the sum charge for phase 2 is indexed n+1 while yours is n-1 and n. You don't explain the removal of Vos, either, but I'm guessing that can be assumed zero for basic analysis purposes.

Comment: Yes, I included the first circuit simply to show the procedure I am following to derive the difference equation.